# Problems while overloading << operation in C++

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, increment, cout

I'm writing the following class

```
class Date {
    int day, month, year;
    int month31[7] = {1,3,5,7,8,10,12};
    int size31 = 7;
    int month30[4] = {4,6,9,11};
    int size30 = 4;
    bool isLeapYear(int yr);
    bool inArray(int val, int *arr, int arrSize);

    public:
    Date(int d, int m, int y);
    Date operator ++ ();
    Date operator ++ (int);
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, Date &d);
    void display() const
    {
        cout <<day<<"-"<<month<<"-"<<year<<endl;
    }
};
```

These are some of the functions.

```
Date:: Date(int d, int m, int y)
{
    day = d;
    month = m;
    year = y;
}

Date Date:: operator ++ ()
{
    day += 1;
    
    if (month == 2) {
        if (!isLeapYear(year) && day > 28) {
            month += 1; day = 1;
        } else if (isLeapYear(year) && day > 29) {
            month += 1; day = 1;
        }
    } else if (day > 30 and inArray(month, month30, size30)) {
        month += 1; day = 1;
    } else if (day > 31 and inArray(month, month31, size31)) {
        month += 1; day = 1;
    }
    
    if (month > 12) {
        year += 1; month = 1;
    }

    return (*this);
}

Date Date:: operator ++ (int)
{
    Date tmp = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return tmp;
}
```

Here I tried to overload the << operator.

```
ostream &operator << (ostream &out, Date &d)
{
    out << d.day <<"-"<< d.month <<"-"<< d.year;
    return out;
}
```

I created an object d1 of class Date.
Now when I'm doing

```
cout << d1 << endl;
```

from main(), it is working fine.
But if I do something like

```
cout << (++d1) << endl;
```

or

```
cout << (d++) << endl;
```

I'm getting errors while compilation.
(I don't think is is a problem with the overloaded increment operator because when I do
(++d1).display or (d1++).display(), It is working fine.)

Anyway, when I'm using cout (with increment), I'm getting this super big error message.

```
    p04.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
p04.cpp:129:10: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘Date’)
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |     ~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~
      |     |        |
      |     |        Date
      |     std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:108:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:108:36: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&)’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)’}
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:117:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]’
  117 |       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:117:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type&)’ {aka ‘std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)’}
  117 |       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:127:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  127 |       operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:127:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)’
  127 |       operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:166:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  166 |       operator<<(long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:166:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘long int’
  166 |       operator<<(long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:170:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  170 |       operator<<(unsigned long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:170:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘long unsigned int’
  170 |       operator<<(unsigned long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:174:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  174 |       operator<<(bool __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:174:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘bool’
  174 |       operator<<(bool __n)
      |                  ~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:853,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/ostream.tcc:91:5: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
   91 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/ostream.tcc:92:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘short int’
   92 |     operator<<(short __n)
      |                ~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:181:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  181 |       operator<<(unsigned short __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:181:33: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘short unsigned int’
  181 |       operator<<(unsigned short __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:853,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/ostream.tcc:105:5: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
  105 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/ostream.tcc:106:20: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘int’
  106 |     operator<<(int __n)
      |                ~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:192:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  192 |       operator<<(unsigned int __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:192:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘unsigned int’
  192 |       operator<<(unsigned int __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:201:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  201 |       operator<<(long long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:201:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘long long int’
  201 |       operator<<(long long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:205:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  205 |       operator<<(unsigned long long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:205:37: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘long long unsigned int’
  205 |       operator<<(unsigned long long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:220:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  220 |       operator<<(double __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:220:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘double’
  220 |       operator<<(double __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:224:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  224 |       operator<<(float __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:224:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘float’
  224 |       operator<<(float __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:232:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  232 |       operator<<(long double __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:232:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘long double’
  232 |       operator<<(long double __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:245:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  245 |       operator<<(const void* __p)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:245:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘const void*’
  245 |       operator<<(const void* __p)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:250:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::nullptr_t) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]’
  250 |       operator<<(nullptr_t)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:250:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
  250 |       operator<<(nullptr_t)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:853,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/ostream.tcc:119:5: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]’
  119 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/ostream.tcc:120:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Date’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__streambuf_type*’ {aka ‘std::basic_streambuf<char>*’}
  120 |     operator<<(__streambuf_type* __sbin)
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/string_view:665:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>)’
  665 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/string_view:665:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:18: note:   ‘Date’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:6517:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&)’
 6517 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:6517:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:18: note:   ‘Date’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/system_error:263:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::error_code&)’
  263 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, const error_code& __e)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/system_error:263:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:14: note:   cannot convert ‘d5.Date::operator++()’ (type ‘Date’) to type ‘const std::error_code&’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |             ~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:506:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT)’
  506 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, _CharT __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:506:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:18: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_CharT’ (‘char’ and ‘Date’)
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:511:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, char)’
  511 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:511:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:14: note:   cannot convert ‘d5.Date::operator++()’ (type ‘Date’) to type ‘char’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |             ~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:517:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, char)’
  517 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:517:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:14: note:   cannot convert ‘d5.Date::operator++()’ (type ‘Date’) to type ‘char’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |             ~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:523:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, signed char)’
  523 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, signed char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:523:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:14: note:   cannot convert ‘d5.Date::operator++()’ (type ‘Date’) to type ‘signed char’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |             ~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:528:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char)’
  528 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, unsigned char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:528:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:14: note:   cannot convert ‘d5.Date::operator++()’ (type ‘Date’) to type ‘unsigned char’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |             ~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:589:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const _CharT*)’
  589 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const _CharT* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:589:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:18: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘Date’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:853,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/ostream.tcc:321:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const char*)’
  321 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/ostream.tcc:321:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:14: note:   cannot convert ‘d5.Date::operator++()’ (type ‘Date’) to type ‘const char*’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |             ~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:606:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const char*)’
  606 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:606:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:14: note:   cannot convert ‘d5.Date::operator++()’ (type ‘Date’) to type ‘const char*’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |             ~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:619:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const signed char*)’
  619 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const signed char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:619:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:14: note:   cannot convert ‘d5.Date::operator++()’ (type ‘Date’) to type ‘const signed char*’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |             ~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:624:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const unsigned char*)’
  624 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const unsigned char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:624:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
p04.cpp:129:14: note:   cannot convert ‘d5.Date::operator++()’ (type ‘Date’) to type ‘const unsigned char*’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |             ~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from p04.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:773:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Ostream, class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>, std::__is_insertable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type, const _Tp&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type>::type std::operator<<(_Ostream&&, const _Tp&)’
  773 |     operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:773:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream: In substitution of ‘template<class _Ostream, class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>, std::__is_insertable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type, const _Tp&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type>::type std::operator<<(_Ostream&&, const _Tp&) [with _Ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>&; _Tp = Date]’:
p04.cpp:129:18:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:773:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>’
p04.cpp:84:10: note: candidate: ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Date&)’ (near match)
   84 | ostream &operator << (ostream &out, Date &d)
      |          ^~~~~~~~
p04.cpp:84:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
p04.cpp:129:14: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Date&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Date’
  129 |     cout << (++d5) <<endl;
      |             ~^~~~~
```

So, where did I go wrong ?

Comment: `ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const Date &d)`.  The `const` allows temporary values like `d++`, as it indicates that you don't want to modify that reference.

Comment: Likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object/1565811